# Bootstrap Tokenfield show empty tags list. Laravel App

Tags: json, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have a problem with autocomplete.

Firslty I get an array with tags:

```
  var tagsList = @json(\App\Helpers\Clients::getTags());
```

And then:

```
    $('#tags').tokenfield({
         beautify:false,
         autocomplete: {
              source: [tagsList],
              delay: 100
         },
        showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
     });
```

This code works correctly. No errors in console. But show the list of tags empty!

If I change tagList by static list, work correctly:

```
   $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
       autocomplete: {
       source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet'],
       delay: 100
       },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
      });
```

[image]

Console debug show the list correctly:

[image]

But in app only show this (repeat, no errors console):

[image]

Looks like css doesnt work but every css is linked correctly.

Any idea what is happenning?¿

console.log(tagsList) throw:

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: can you try changing `source: [tagsList]` to `source: tagsList`

Comment: Without [ ]  console show error: `jquery-ui.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function`

Comment: The strange is that no errors! simply show the empty list

Comment: could you add the output of `console.log(tagsList);` to your question

Comment: I have updated my question with console.log(tagsList) result. Show object correctly

Comment: I think the problem is that `tagsList` is an object but needs to be an array.

Comment: I would change the output of `\App\Helpers\Clients::getTags()` to a sequential array so `@json` can convert it to a JS array instead of an object, what you could do otherwise is `source: Object.values(tokenList)`

Comment: If I put: `var array = Object.values(tagsList);` and I use array instead tagList result is the same.

Comment: so `source: array`?

Comment: Finally your suggestion are correct. But without []. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How can I make appoiment for you @Remul ?

Comment: I will create an answer and you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tokenfields `source` attribute needs an array, but you are passing an object to it.

The problem is that you do not have a sequential array so `@json` cannot convert it to an array but instead converts it to an object.

**Solution 1**

Convert the output from `\App\Helpers\Clients::getTags()` to a sequential array.

**Solution 2**

get the object values in JS and pass it to `source`

```
$('#tags').tokenfield({
    beautify:false,
    autocomplete: {
        source: Object.values(tagsList),
        delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Joaquin

How about you only use array to your source property?

```
   $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
        autocomplete: {
        source: Object.values(taglist),
        delay: 100
       },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
   });
```